# How to align figure to the right

Tags: html, css

I want to align a figure element to the right, i tried float and it worked but i cannot clear the float so is there is any other ways ?

```
<figure>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596070779006-15d9c5ff73d7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
</figure>
```

Comment: what is your goal ? to align the img to the right, or the figure ? if the figure - then without wrapping it with another container, it wan't work ( you can use directon:rtl , but it depends on the outer wrapper ). i would suggest wrapping with an outer div + setting the figure class with text-align:righ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an empty space to the left of <figure>

```
figure{ text-align: right}
```

In case that's not enough, replace it with:

```
figure{ text-align: right; display: block}
figcaption{ text-align: left}     /* only when needed */
```

if you want to put anything on the left side of <figure>, a <div> or some other element, you need this:

```
div, figure{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle}
/* you may split them, add margin;  vertical-align: top | middle | bottom */
<div> .... </div><figure><img src="img.jpg" alt="img"></figure>
```

if you want text to flow around <figure> - float is only possibility. Float only for <figure> should do the trick and be safe

```
figure{ float: right}  
<p><figure><img src="..." alt="..."></figure>Lorem ipsum dolor sit... </p>
```

There is one more group of features, probably you won't use them

```
figure{ position: relative; left: 60%}     /* moves 60% right */
figure{ position: fixed; right: 10px;}     /* fixes permanently to the right edge of the browser; you may change the number */
figure{ position: absolute; right: 20vh}   /* moves it to right above the content */
```

The last one is neither kind nor easy `display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;` is invented to  easily distribute multiple items, for one image it would be more pain then profit

Answer (score 1):

```
figure {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```